# Java - Finding An Element Within An Array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I am currently trying to figure out how to search my array to look for a particular element within the array. The user will input the name they want to find, and my program should return to the user the seat they are sitting in. Adding passengers is done through another method. So, if I had someone called "Tim Jones" sitting in seat 5, if I used this method I would type "Tim Jones" and the program should tell me that Tim Jones is sitting in seat 5.

The current output I am getting is just the else statement, the passenger is not found no matter what I try. Any tips? Thanks in advance.

```
private static void findPassengerSeat(String airplaneRef[]) {
    String passengerName;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter passenger's name."); // asks user for passenger name.
    passengerName = input.next(); // user input stored under variable passengerName.
    for (int i = 0; i < airplaneRef.length; i++) { // for i, if i is less than the length of the array airplaneRef, increment i.
        if (airplaneRef[i].equalsIgnoreCase(passengerName)) { // iterates through all elements in the array, ignoring case sensitivity and looks for the passenger.
            int seat = i;
            System.out.println(passengerName + " is sitting in seat s" + seat); // prints name of passenger and what seat they are sitting in.
        } else {
            System.out.println("Passenger not found.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have a *Tim* in your array, but due to using `next` instead of `nextLine`, you don't have a *Tim Jones*.

Comment: This is why you should learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get rid of the `else` otherwise you're only evaluating the first index of your array and passing all the rest.

The following should do its charm : you basically go through the list of all the passengers, and only if none of them corresponds to the input, you state that the passenger is not found.

```
for (int i = 0; i < airplaneRef.length; i++) { // for i, if i is less than the length of the array airplaneRef, increment i.
    if (airplaneRef[i].equalsIgnoreCase(passengerName)) { // iterates through all elements in the array, ignoring case sensitivity and looks for the passenger.
        int seat = i;
        System.out.println(passengerName + " is sitting in seat s" + seat); // prints name of passenger and what seat they are sitting in.
        return;
    }
}
System.out.println("Passenger not found.");
```